# std::all_of not accepting class member function as function with 1 argument

Tags: c++, c++11, std, member

I can't figure what I am doing wrong with this `std::all_of` call.

I have a class Statistics:

```
class Statistics {
public:
bool isDataSet() const { return m_data.size() > 0; }
private:
std::vector<double> m_data;
};
```

Each instance of Statistics class corresponds to a certain object.

In another function in a different file I want to display statistics only if data has been initialized in **all** `Statistics` instances. I want to use `std::all_of` function in the following manner:

```
if( std::all_of(m_stats.begin(), m_stats.end(), &Statistics::isDataSet) ) {
...
}
```

where `std::vector<Statistics*> m_stats.`

The compiler reports error in that the 'predicate term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments'. As far as I know, each class member passes this pointer as the first parameter, so `Statistics::isDataSet()` should actually be a function with 1 parameter. But `std::all_of` sees this wrong.

Am I wrong in my assumption that `Statistics::isDataSet()` should be accepted as a function with 1 parameter in `std::all_of()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use

```
std::bind(&Statistics::isDataSet, std::placeholders::_1)
```

or

```
[](const Statistics& s) { return s.isDataSet(); }
```

instead of  `&Statistics::isDataSet` in call to `all_of`. latter expect a *callable* type (as predicate) and will pass an instance of `Statistics` to it. Specifying member-function w/o instance obviously not enough to make a call

Comment: +1, the latter is more intuitive to the non-bind-crowd, but both are viable.

Comment: Thanks! `[](const Statistics* s) { return s->isDataSet(); }` also did the trick! Why doesn't `[x]() {return x->isDtaSet();}` work?

Comment: @PavloDyban the last lambda is a __nulary__ callable object (function) actually, but unary predicate expected

Comment: @PavloDyban: and btw, just think, what you will write instead of 'x' here: `[x]() { return x.isDataSet(); }` ?? At call site you have no any `Statictics` instance yet :)

Comment: Another option is `std::mem_fun(&Statistics::isDataSet)`. It's less flexible and it's deprecated in C++11, but it's more concise for the cases it does apply to.

Comment: @PavloDyban: `[x]() {return x->isDtaSet();}` is a lambda that tries to capture a variable named `x` from its surrounding scope and takes no parameters. There is no `x` in your code, so it can't capture `x`, and `all_of` requires a predicate that takes one parameter. So there are two reasons it doesn't work.

Comment: @SteveJessop I thought C++11 lambdas are similar to python lambdas. In the latter, you write `x` for a variables in scope. I was expecting that each iterated value would be passed as `x`, but I forgot the std logic behind `all_of`. `all_of` calls a function as passes each iterated item, so the lambda variable must be empty, the parameter is used instead.

Comment: @PavloDyban: in the Python `lambda x : x.isDataSet()`, `x` is a parameter, it is not a capture. Therefore it's similar to zaufi's lambda and not to yours.

Comment: Are the two solutions really equivalent in terms of constness ? On my problem, 
this    std::bind( &Email::isAddressValid(), std::placeholders::_1 )     doesn't work but this   [](const Email& e) { return e.isAddressValid(); }    works.