# Why does `std::all_of` not use `std::invoke`?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

It has been noted in similar questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461204/stdall-of-not-accepting-class-member-function-as-function-with-1-argument)) that you cannot pass class method pointers as predicates to `std::all_of`.

However, with C++17, we have `std::invoke`, which should make it easy for `std::all_of` and similar functions to accept member function (and even member variable) pointers.

To be more specific, the following does not compile on GCC 9.2:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct S {
    bool check() const { return true; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<S> vs;
    std::all_of(vs.begin(), vs.end(), &S::check);
}
```

This [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/f3OzUh) contains some example code and a toy version of `all_of` using invoke.

Why this restriction? Am I missing something? I imagined that when `std::invoke` was standardised, it should also have been applied to appropriate STL functions.

Comment: See the Godbolt link. Calling member functions is one of the purposes of `invoke`.

Comment: It is invoked with `*it` as the member object, where `it` is the current iterator in the `all_of` implementation.

Comment: I see your point now. Missed it's a vector of `S`.

Comment: @StoryTeller No problem.

Comment: Looking closer to your question, I would assume your code would work. Maybe a bug in the implementation?

Answer (score 6):

Reason 1:  <del>No one has ever proposed it.</del>  [P0312R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0312r1.html) proposed to make pointer-to-member-functions callable in the language but was rejected (no consensus for making this change).

Reason 2:  With lambda's (and `std::bind` prior to that), there's very little motivation.  If `S` is a std-defined type (e.g. `vector`), the member-to-pointer option would be illegal for other reasons.

```
std::all_of(vs.begin(), vs.end(), [](auto const& s) {return s.check();});
```

Comment: I think `std::mem_fn` is a more compelling reason (in terms of readabilility) compared to `bind`.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned `mem_fn`.  You're right that it is compelling.  For some reason I personally always have a hard time with that family of functions.  I find the lambda syntax most readable.  But I freely admit that my preference is very subjective.

Comment: Reason 3: It shouldn't use invoke and we should just make pointers to members invokable (I feel obligated to make this comment wherever relevant).

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I am aware of lambdas. However, it feels a bit silly to have to write a lambda to express a concept that *already exists* in the language (namely, method pointers). Not to mention the added boilerplate and the fact that this is the exact use case of `std::invoke`.

Comment: By the way: Why would the pointer-to-member be illegal if `S` is a std-defined type?

Comment: It looks like I should have qualified that with *non-virtual* member functions.  In C++17, [member.functions]/p2 says that an implementation can add default arguments and/or overload non-virtual member functions as long as any call to the overload set would behave as if the correct overload is selected.  This means that pointers to such members can end up being ambiguous since those expressions don't include arguments for overload resolution.  The draft C++20 expands this concept by saying that taking the address of a function `F` is unspecified unless `F` is specified to be _addressable_.

Comment: Interesting catch, I can see how that could lead to ambiguity. Thanks.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: There was a [proposal submitted to make member pointers directly callable: Making pointers to members callable](https://wg21.link/P0312). It was rejected, [according to this report for seemingly dubious reasons](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2016/07/06/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-oulu-june-2016/).

Comment: Thanks @NicolBolas.  I've updated my answer with this information.

Comment: @Barry I agree, although your comment seems to be politically motivated ;) I feel obliged however to point out that `std::invoke` also allows you to use pointers to member *variables*.

Comment: @DanielS I didn't specifically say pointers to member functions - I said all pointers to members.

Answer (score 6):

The next generation of algorithms (those in the `std::ranges` namespace) accept predicates that are called with `std::invoke`, exactly as you suggest (https://godbolt.org/z/uaPoJf):

```
std::ranges::all_of(vs.begin(), vs.end(), &S::check);
```

or shorter (https://godbolt.org/z/_qiO8G):

```
std::ranges::all_of(vs, &S::check);
```

Furthermore, they accept an additional argument called a “projection”, which is a unary transformation function passed to the algorithm that gets applied to each element before the algorithm operates on the element. For example (https://godbolt.org/z/gWY-OR):

```
std::ranges::all_of(vs, std::logical_not(), &S::check);
```

You can already use all of the above with either Casey Carter’s [cmcstl2](https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2) or Eric Niebler’s [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).